# Why was "taxi into position and hold" changed to "line up and wait" in the USA?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control, radio-communications, phraseology

How come taxi into position and hold changed into "Line up and wait?" Did the old phraseology cause misunderstandings, or did it seem dated?

Answer (score 12):

To ensure international consistency. *Line up and wait* is the standard phraseology used almost everywhere in the world, as defined by the ICAO, so it was confusing for pilots that another phrase was used to mean the same thing when flying to the USA.